# program crashes when typecasting void* to int in c++

Tags: c++

I am using a library which has callback function with void* as a parameter. I need to get int from this void*, below code works fine in c but not in c++

In c:

```
void *ptr;
int n = (int)ptr;
```

So in c++ i tried below

```
int n = atoi(static_cast<const char*>(ptr));
```

This crashes when i run. Please help me with the right way to convert void* to int in c++

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can use `int n = (int)ptr;` in C++ as well. Or `int n = static_cast<int>(ptr);`.

Comment: A side note, you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` for the integer type, they are guaranteed to be wide enough so the pointer value fits. Google them up.

Comment: The C code will work in C++ as well. `atoi` does something compleely different (in C as well).

Comment: `atoi` is for converting a textual representation of a number to `int`. It's inherited from C, it isn't something new to C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Both gives error/warning "error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]"

Comment: That is probably because the `void *` is 64-bit, and your `int` size is smaller (32-bit).  You can easily test this at compile-time using `static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int), "Void pointers have size different than an int");`

Comment: You can add an `intptr_t` cast to silence the warning: `int n = (int)(intptr_t)ptr;`. (If you're sure that the value encoded in the pointer is always representable as `int`.)

Comment: I recommend using `unsigned` integers.  Most addresses are unsigned and use the full range of an unsigned integer.  Some processors may use signed values when performing relative branching, but this may not have anything to do with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For this case don't use `atoi` it means something else entirely.

For your use you should either cast or just convert the `void*` into `int` type

```
int n = static_cast<int>(ptr);
```

or just

```
int n = (int)ptr;
```

I used int for these examples, but don't. Use `intptr_t` for signed numbers or `uintptr_t` for unsigned numbers.

Comment: Both the solutions results in warning/error in c++. Thnaks for suggesting intptr_t , below cast works fine.        ``` static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(void_p)) ```

Answer (score 0):

```
static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr))
```

This works fine.